# How to connect an NSControl to an Action *and* a label in IB?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, action, nsslider

I'm trying to connect an NSSlider to both a label (takeIntValueFrom) to show its value, and an IBAction in my .xib.  However, connecting either one of them un-connects the other.

I could do this programmatically, but I'd like to know if there's a way in IB?

Comment: Can you make available a sample test project which shows what you have tried?

Comment: +1 for OSX question, (However I added OSX)

Comment: @ericgorr. Thanks, but I guess it's a moot point now.

Comment: Why moot? It is certainly possible to bind the value of a label to a slider value and have that slider send it's action message to the file owner in IB.

Comment: I don't know how to upload a project, but in any case: add a slider and label to any view. Create an action for the slider by control-dragging to the .h. Action set. Now control drag from the slider to the textfield... the previous action connection becomes unset. I said moot because I thought Anoop's answer reflected what I was seeing. Maybe I'm missing a step if you are able to do it?

Comment: You can easily use https://github.com/ to make a project available. 

You can check out: http://www.wmdeveloper.com/2010/07/cocoa-binding-gui-application-without.html If this is what you are looking for, I can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No this is not possible**

Multiaction is not possible for OSX application.

Comment: Thanks.Will do it via an outlet instead.